# Problems with responsive images in absolute positioned containers

Tags: html, css

I'm kind of stuck when trying to use this slideshow plugin:

https://github.com/iamvery/galleriffic

I'm using this because it has page pagination.

Anyway,

the problem is the container has to be position: absolute which means I must give it a height so elements below respect its height.

The problem with this is the images. I want them to be responsive.

So basically I'd like to use max-width: 100%;.

The problem is obviously if my container is for e.g 600px high and my images are responsive then my image height will decrease under that 600px and leave white space.

I've tried having img width 100% but fixed height but then they skew as your resize the browser.

I'm not sure if there is a solution.

Any ideas?

Example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/u08vrpt2/

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="image">
        <div class="image__item">
            <img src="https://s15.postimg.org/qwsiomo97/test.jpg" alt="test image">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.image {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 500px;
    background: grey;
}

.image__item {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why the container needs to be absolute?
If we remove that, you still having the same behavior

```css
.image {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1200px;
  background: grey;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <div class="image__item">
    <img src="https://s15.postimg.org/qwsiomo97/test.jpg" alt="test image">
  </div>
</div>
<p>This text respect the image height</p>
```

Comment: Because the plugin doesn't load the images properly if I remove it. When you go to each slide it jumps.